# Integrating the product of the multivariate pdf and cdf.

Tags: probability-theory, multivariable-calculus, conditional-probability, multiple-integral

Consider three i.i.d random variable $X_{0,1,2}\in [0,1]$ given by pdf $f(x)$ and cdf $F(x)$, then,
We can calculate the probability,
$$
P(X_0<X_1,X_2) = \int_{0}^1 f(x_0)\int_{x_0}^1f(x_1) \; dx_1\int_{x_0}^1f(x_2)d(x_2)\;dx_0 
\\= \int_{0}^1 f(x_0)[1-F(x_0)]^2\;dx_0\\
=\frac{1}{3}
$$
This is equal to 1/3 either by using probabilistic reasoning, i.e. the probability that 1 of these 3 variables is the smallest is 1/3 (as they all have the same chance of being the smallest) or by using the integral formula,
$$
f(x)F^{n-1}(x)=\frac{1}{n}\frac{dF^n(x)}{dx}
$$
and calculating the integral directly.

I am struggling to generalise this in the multivariate case, where $\bf{X_{0,1,2}}\in[0,1]^N$ are $N-$dimensional random variables from joint distribution $f(x_1,...,x_N)$ and cdf $F(x_1,...,x_N)$. Here we no longer have the integral formula nor the probabilistic intuition in order to calculate the expression,
$$
P(\bigcap_{i=1}^N \{X_{0,i}<X_{1,i},X_{2,i}\})
$$

Any hints or solutions welcome.